# EPSON WorkForce WF-7610 printing not sharp lines

Tags: printing, epson, ubuntu-drivers

I installed my EPSON WorkForce WF-7610 printer on Ubuntu 16.04 and I'm not really satisfied with printings.

I'm printing architecture technical drawings. Circles are fuzzy and seem to be dashed or dotted lines, but they are intended to be continuous. Even straight lines don't look really good, they are a little bit haired.

I printed the same drawing with the same application (QCAD) in Mac OS environment and results were much better. Looks like it is something related with Ubuntu drivers for this machine.

Any help?

Comment: Which version of ubuntu are you usging, which version of cups?

Comment: Epson supply a generic driver for linux; sounds like you are into quality tings and need a better quality driver David; if you look at turboprint http://www.zedonet.com/en_p_turboprint_driver.phtml?printer=Epson_WorkForceWF7610 as they have long specialised in very high quality printer drivers; for their work, they ask for a contribution, so they can put food on the table;

Comment: cups is already the newest version (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.3).

Comment: I use ubuntu 16.04 LTS